# How to import external jar file into Firefox fennec moz.build file?

Tags: firefox, fennec

I'm building a customized version of Firefox Fennec, and recently added an UI that uses android's RecyclerView. So I want to import android-support-v7-recyclerview.jar to my moz.build file but don't know how.

I have tried to add android-support-v7-recyclerview.jar to gbjar.extra_jars, but it gives me exceptions below.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView$LayoutManager
 0:46.88    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
 0:46.88    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2615)
 0:46.88    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1860)
 0:46.88    at org.mozilla.gecko.annotationProcessors.utils.GeneratableElementIterator.<init>(GeneratableElementIterator.java:32)
 0:46.88    at org.mozilla.gecko.annotationProcessors.AnnotationProcessor.main(AnnotationProcessor.java:74)
 0:46.88 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager
 0:46.88    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
 0:46.88    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
 0:46.88    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 0:46.88    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
 0:46.88    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
 0:46.88    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
 0:46.88    ... 5 more
```

Is there something to do more in moz.build?

Answer (score 0):

There is Makefile.in file in /mozilla-central/mobile/android/base/
Find ALL_JARS and add your external jar file there!